# How to set up routes for Laravel 5 so I can access from public folder

Tags: php, laravel-5

When I try to run some other route trought localhost/project/public/acp or localhost/acp it say folder not found but when use localhost:8000/acp it works fine here is my routes:

```
Route::get('acp', 'CommentController@admin');
```

I use Linux server... And what is right way to put Laravel app in production?

Also this works fine: localhost/project/public/ but other routes no....

Comment: It sounds like you have more than one webserver (Laravel's development one on 8000 and something else like Apache/nginx on the default 80), and haven't properly configured your main one.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `php artisan serve`, your site runs on `localhost:8000` and nothing outside of the `public` directory is directly accessible. `php artisan serve` should never be used to serve a production site, it's only for development usage.

If you want it to run on `localhost/project/public/acp` you'd have to point your webserver's document root at the parent folder of `project`. This is different depending on which server you use and not advisable because of what follows.

Seeing the `public` folder in the URL of a deployed Laravel site would be indicative of a significant security issue, as it'd make private files (like `.env`) possibly accessible, and if you ever made a mistake in your server/PHP config, it might allow your PHP files to be read as plain text.

Comment: But then how can I access Laravel app without php artisan serve ?

Comment: @Vladimir With a real webserver like Apache or nginx. http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/installation